# Unset the empty values of array bash

Tags: bash

My script is setting array from grep results in such a way that empty grep results are also being stored in array.

Eg.

```
set -x
echo "${Arr[@]}" 
+ echo '' 'word' '' 'word2'
```

Can someone help unset those empty values
so that echo "${#Arr[@]}" gives 2 instead of 4

Tried

```
var=-1 && for i in "${Input_Arr[@]}"; do var=$((var+1));  if [ -z "$i" ]; then unset "${Input_Arr[$var]}"; fi; done
```

But it isn't working

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, there's no need to invent a dummy index - you can access the array's indices using the indirection operator `!`

Second, `"${Input_Arr[$var]}"` is the element's *value*; `unset` needs the element's *name*, `Input_Arr[$var]` or just `Input_Arr[var]`, since it's already an arithmetic context). So given:

```
$ arr=(foo '' bar '' baz)
$ declare -p arr
declare -a arr=([0]="foo" [1]="" [2]="bar" [3]="" [4]="baz")
```

then

```
$ for i in ${!arr[@]}; do [[ -z ${arr[i]} ]] && unset arr[i]; done
```

leaves

```
$ declare -p arr
declare -a arr=([0]="foo" [2]="bar" [4]="baz")
```

---

This also works for associative arrays - with suitable adjustments for the non-numeric keys (including double quoting expansions to prevent potential split + glob):

```
$ declare -A Arr=(['1st val']=foo ['2nd val']='' ['3rd val']=bar ['4th val']='' ['5th val']=baz)

$ declare -p Arr
declare -A Arr=(["5th val"]="baz" ["2nd val"]="" ["4th val"]="" ["3rd val"]="bar" ["1st val"]="foo" )

$ for i in "${!Arr[@]}"; do [[ -z ${Arr[$i]} ]] && unset Arr["$i"]; done

$ declare -p Arr
declare -A Arr=(["5th val"]="baz" ["3rd val"]="bar" ["1st val"]="foo" )
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want the remaining array elements to be collapsed to consecutive indexes starting from zero, it's probably easiest to make a copy of the array:

```
arr1=(foo '' bar '')
arr2=()
for val in "${arr1[@]}"; do
    [[ $val ]] && arr2+=( "$val" )
done
```

That would leave `arr2` as `declare -a arr2=([0]="foo" [1]="bar")`, i.e. the index of `bar` was changed from 2 to 1 to avoid leaving a hole.

You could also do that in-place by just copying the individual elements and unsetting the last ones, but it's more manual work.